# C coding for GTK+ (a simple case)

Tags: c, gtk

I am learning C and compiling the codes with GTK+. I have a simple GTK+ of

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Could you please give me a hint how can I insert C processing codes within this structure? For example, I want to read the content of a file and display within the gtk+ window.

Comment: Question is too broad and the sample code you pasted is too generic. Try to ask more specific questions ...

Comment: I think you should first learn C by coding simple command line programs and then start coding for Gtk. Are you able to code in C some code to show on the terminal the content of a file (i.e. the simplified equivalent of the `cat` command on Linux)?

Comment: yes I know how to use fopen or other methods to read the contents of a file in terminal, I just was not sure how to fit the C codes within the gtk environment. As Paul quoted, my missing point was how to use `g_signal_connect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a "callback" that will respond to some "event".

This is how all GUI frameworks work - they're all "event driven".

The specific GTK+ 2.0 API is "g_signal_connect()".

Here's a very simple example:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtkevents/

Here is a much more extensive tutorial:

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/

If you work through this tutorial - you'll learn a lot of useful material about GTK+ - and quite possibly learn a lot of useful information about C, too.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Once you learned more C, you might consider using Glib stuff like [g_io_add_watch](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch)